# best method to find location in indoors iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to find the location of user using corelocation framework in my app ,
but 
it doesn't showing good results , can anyone please tell me how can i get location accurately in indoors ?

thanks in advance

regards

Comment: Open the nearest window, stand on one leg, and hold the phone high over your head.

Comment: can u please tell me whats wrong in my question ?

Comment: this is a programming site, and unfortunately no amount of code wizardry will prevent walls from blocking radio waves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, about the exact physical environment but if wifi access points are available then you can use sdk available from skyhook wireless or navision to locate your current position in case the accuracy of the gps position is not good.

This is not a failsafe approach, but may work better in areas where data is available about wireless ap.

Comment: thanks for reply and yeah in my area , i have many wifi AP's ,  can u please link be example to how to use wifi AP to get location ?

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can't get an accurate location indoors using Core Location.  (What's wrong with your question is in assuming that you can, before asking how to do the impossible.)

You might get lucky if you are under to a tent roof that is paper thin or near a large window below lots of wide open sky, or happen to be between 3 or more nearby wifi access points whose locations are all accurately and precisely registered with whichever wifi database(s) Apple is using.